# Как сделать оплату в Telegram-боте через PayPal

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Столкнулся с проблемой, что в BotFather нет системы оплаты PayPal, а как подключить - не знаю. Буду благодарен всем, кто поможет разобраться.